# jquery FormData is not working in IE8 and IE9

Tags: jquery

I am uploading image without refresh page. For this i am using jQuery FormData tag for uploading images in my website but it does not work in IE8 and IE9. Is there any other so it should work in IE8/IE9 or i need to use another plugin for uploading image without refresh page

or is there any other method that is compatible to all browsers, ipad, tablet and all phones?

Comment: There is no jQuery FormData tag, if you mean the native FormData tag, that's not supported in IE8 or 9.

Comment: [FormData Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Maybe he's talking about the jQuery Form plugin?

Comment: is there any other method that is compatible to all browsers, ipad, tablet and all phones?

Comment: For non supporting browser the only option is to actually submit a form, and usually a hidden iFrame is used to avoid page reloads etc, but it's a lot more complicated than using FormData.

Answer (score -1):

IE doesn't support ajaxForm... You should upload image in different form for IE.
call ajax, check the browser if browser is ie then written different code for ie.

```
    if(browsercheck=="Internet explorer")
                    {
                                window.location.reload();
                    }
                else
                $(".log1").prop('src',JSON.parse(localStorage["myimg"]));

                //alert("shdf,sdhf");
            }
        });


<script type="text/javascript">
var browsercheck;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
         url: "chbro.php",
         success: function(datas)
         {
             browsercheck=datas;
         }
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#upload_photo').click(function() {
                 if(browsercheck=="Internet explorer")
                 {
                     $('#iframe2').click();
                 }
            else    
                {
                     $('input[type=file]#upload_myphoto').click();
                }

  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: is there any other method that is compatible to all browsers, ipad, tablet and all phones?

Comment: ajaxForm is only method that supports all browser excepts ie